# ¿Cómo comparar adecuadamente dos fechas?

Tags: sql-server

Estoy realizando una validación en `MSSQL` pero no puedo hacer que funcione correctamente, este es un ejemplo de lo que sucede:

```
DECLARE @fecha1 DATETIME = '11/09/2019 12:11:00'
DECLARE @fecha2 DATETIME = '09/10/2019 12:25:00'
IF (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@fecha2,103)) < (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@fecha1,103)) 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('LA FECHA2 ES MENOR QUE LA FECHA1.', 16, 1)
        RETURN
    END
```

En este caso, solo quiero comparar la fecha sin la hora, por lo tanto uso `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10)fecha,103)`, pero la fecha2(octubre) es mayor que la fecha1(septiembre) y aún así entra al `RAISEERROR`.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal y cuál sería la forma correcta de realizar este tipo de comparaciones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es, que al usar el `CONVERT` terminas haciendo una comparación entre cadenas, por lo que se comparan con el orden lexicográfico, en tu caso: `09/11/2019` es menor a `10/09/2019`. Tienes dos/tres opciones:

#### 1. Convertir pero con un formato consistente para la comparación (ISO):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@fecha1,112), 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@fecha2,112)

---------- ----------
20191109   20190910
```

#### 2. Re transformar a fecha

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@fecha1,103)), 
       CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@fecha2,103))

                       
----------------------- -----------------------
2019-09-11 00:00:00.000 2019-10-09 00:00:00.000
```

En caso de SQL server 2008 o superior, también:

#### 3. puedes convertir directamente a `DATE`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,@fecha1,103), 
       CONVERT(DATE,@fecha2,103)
```

Por último, otra forma pragmática de comparar las fecha, podría ser calcular las diferencias en días:

```
IF (DATEDIFF(DAY, @fecha1, @fecha2) < 0) 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('LA FECHA2 ES MENOR QUE LA FECHA1.', 16, 1)
        RETURN
    END
```

Comment: Evito sugerir la última opción a toda costa, ya que luego se presenta ese tipo de comparaciones en las claúsulas WHERE y evitan que se utilicen índices disponibles generando consultas lentas.

Answer (score 3):

Hay 2 problemas en esto:

1. Estás usando un formato que depende de configuraciones de idioma y fecha. Lo ideal es usar el formato ISO-8601 que puede ser `YYYYMMDD`, `YYYYMMDD hh:mi:ss.mss`, o `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mi:ss.mss`. Presta atención al último formato que cambia el espacio por una T.
2. Siempre que tengas valores de fechas en un tipo fecha (como datetime, date, datetime2) lo ideal es mantenerlos en ese tipo en vez de hacer conversiones a cadenas de caracteres.

Siguiendo las recomendaciones, quedaría así:

```
DECLARE @fecha1 DATETIME = '20191109 12:11:00';
DECLARE @fecha2 DATETIME = '20190910 12:25:00';
IF @fecha2 < @fecha1
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('LA FECHA2 ES MENOR QUE LA FECHA1.', 16, 1);
        RETURN;
    END;
```

Comment: Gracias Luis, pero si quiero ignorar la parte de la hora. Digamos que requiero comparar únicamente la fecha como '20191109' = '20191109' o caso contrario comparar solo la parte del tiempo ignorando el día. ¿cómo se puede realizar este tipo de comparaciones?

Comment: Para igualdades de fecha, puedes convertir a tipo `date`, ya que es de las pocas conversiones que permite usar índices. Para la porción del tiempo, existe el tipo `time`. En última instancia, puedes usar `CONVERT( char(8), Fecha, 112)` para utilizar el valor de fecha en formato ISO-8601.

Comment: Se me olvidó comentar que es necesaria la compatibilidad con SQL server 2005, por lo tanto no puedo hacer uso de `date` o `time`.

Comment: Entonces simplemente usa los formatos 112 para fechas, 108 para tiempo, y 120, 121 o 126 para fecha y tiempo con algún valor truncado.

Comment: Es importante que piensen en actualizarse. Las versiones 2008 ya no tienen soporte y cada vez será más complicado realizar pruebas de migración.

Comment: Por el momento solo unos pocos servidores que aún cuentan con 2005, espero los actualicen pronto.